# Absolutely positioned content of flexlider slides, disappear on mobile iOS safari and chrome and desktop safari, but not on desktop

Tags: mobile, safari, positioning, flexslider, absolute

I am using flexslider but i don't necessarily know if this is a flexslider problem or just to do with how I have positioned the contents of each slide.
Basically, I have a left block of text, and a right hand side image on each slide... when this responds to mobile devices, I stack them vertically using absolute positioning. 
This seems to work file when previewed on desktop, however when I load it on my iphone, or on Safari, the contents of each slide disappear.

I cant for the life of me figure out why this is, as it seems fine on chrome.

To view the site, click below:

[toddpadwick.co.uk/main-index.html](http://toddpadwick.co.uk/main-index.html)

Can any one help? im really struggling here!

the contents of each slide are as follows: (i have simplified it for the purpose of this post)

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li><!-- slide-->
        <div class="caption"><!-- THIS IS THE LEFT SIDE TEXT BOX -->
            <div class="title">
                lorum ipsum dolar sit amet
            </div><!-- END TITLE -->
        </div><!-- END CAPTION -->

        <div class="teaser"><!-- THIS IS THE RIGHT HAND SIDE IMAGE -->
            <div class="image" style="background-image:url(teasers/image.png);"></div>
        </div><!-- END TEASER -->
    </li><!-- end slide-->
</ul><!-- END SLIDES-->
```

and here is CSS

```
.flexslider .slides, .flexslider .slides > li {
    height: 100%;
}

.flexslider .slides li {
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
}




.slides li .caption {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0.7s;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out 0.7s;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    width:40%;
    opacity:0.4;
    display: table;
    float: left;
}


.slides li.flex-active-slide .caption {
    opacity:1;
}

.slides li .caption .title {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left:100px;
}


.slides li .teaser {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0.6s;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in 0.6s;
    width:60%;
    height:90%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    display:table;
    padding:20px 60px 40px 20px;
    position: absolute;

}

.slides li .teaser .image {
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[toddpadwick.co.uk/main-index.html](http://toddpadwick.co.uk/main-index.html)